# In WPF, how can I make data from one binding feed into multiple columns?

Tags: wpf, listview, grid

I am trying to display an array as grid of numbers, with multiple columns and multiple rows.

I set up a ListView with multiple columns bound to my array, but the elements are repeated in each column, so that the data looks like:

```
-------+--------+-------
First  | First  | First 
Second | Second | Second
```

rather than:

```
-------+--------+-------
First  | Second | Third
Fourth | Fifth  | Sixth
```

How can I set up the ListView to display the data as in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

The default items panel for a `ListView` is a vertically-oriented `StackPanel`. Since each number comes as a separate item for the `ListView` and each row is bound to an item, you can't have different columns in one row bind to different items in the bound collection.

However, you can have a `ListBox` or a `ListView` that uses [`WrapPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx) as items panel. If you use `ListView`, you'll have single-column items, and the wrap panel will take care of the proper items layout. However, I'd actually stick with `ListBox`, unless you need some ofthe advanced ListView functionality.

To change the items panel, use the [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) property. Here's an example in XAML:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

The alternative is to change the `ControlTemplate` for the `ListView` and use the [`IsItemsHost`](http://IsItemsHost="True") property (specify `IsItemsHost="True"`) on the panel that you want to act as the items panel.

**Edit**: Updated to use the proper terminology. When I said item container, I meant items panel. That's what happens when answering from an iPhone.

Comment: How would I do that (changing the ItemContainer I mean)?